# Cannot receive text over local TCP connection

Tags: android, c++, tcp, android-source

Sending text over local TCP connection succeeds!
Sending text from Ubuntu to AOSP over local ip address. For some reason it works to accept text with a third-party apk app. But it does not work in C++ environment inside the service.
I've tried different variations of the code. I can't accept the text. Error: "Connection refused" OR "Failed recv: Transport endpoint is not connected".

The service is successfully allowed to use the internet. Checked with.

```
static const String16 sAccessWifiStatePermission("android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE");
static const String16 sInternetPermission("android.permission.INTERNET");
static const String16 sAccessNetworkStatePermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE");
...
bool checksAccessNetworkStatePermission = permissionChecker.checkPermissionForPreflight(
            sAccessNetworkStatePermission, attributionSource, String16(), AppOpsManager::OP_NONE)!= permission::PermissionChecker::PERMISSION_HARD_DENIED;
...
```

I use different ports, for example, 5030..5033. And use local ip address of smartphone: 192.168.2.110. I specify this address in c++ code in AOSP or use INADDR_ANY.
Why can't I accept the text ?

One of the code variants that can't accept text:

```
std::string receiveTextTcp(int port) {

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (fd < 0) {
     ALOGI("Failed socket: %s", strerror(errno));
    return "";
  }
ALOGI("fd : %d, port:%d", fd, port);
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    int reuse_flag = 1;

int result = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_flag, sizeof(reuse_flag));
if (result < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed setsockopt: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
}

int bind_result = bind(fd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr));

if (bind_result < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed bind: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
}

result = listen(fd, 1);
if (result < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed listen: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
}

  char buffer[1024];
  int bytes_received = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
  if (bytes_received < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed recv: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
    
  }

  ALOGI("Failed buffer: %s, port:%d", buffer, port);


  close(fd);


   return "";
}
```

A successful code variant that successfully sends text to a PC:

```
bool SendData(const std::string& ip, int port, const std::string& text) {

  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed to create socket: %s, sockfd:%d", strerror(errno), sockfd);
    return false;
  }

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

  // Use inet_pton instead of inet_addr
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
     ALOGI("Invalid IP address: %s", ip.c_str() );
    close(sockfd);
    return false;
  }

  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
     ALOGI("Failed to connect to server: %s", strerror(errno) );
    close(sockfd);
    return false;
  }


const char* message = text.c_str();
size_t message_len = strlen(message);

if (send(sockfd, message, message_len, 0) < 0) {
     ALOGI("Failed send, err: %s . message:%s", strerror(errno), message );
    close(sockfd);
    return false;
  } else{
    ALOGI("send ok. message:%s", message );
  } 

  close(sockfd);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Transport endpoint is not connected" error is `errno` 107, aka `ENOTCONN`.  Android runs on top of Linux, and the Linux [`recv()` documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) says:

> ENOTCONN
> The socket is associated with a connection-oriented protocol and has not been connected (see [connect(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) and [accept(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)).

You cannot use `recv()` (or `send()`) on a TCP socket that you are `listen()`'ing on.  Instead, you must first `accept()` a client that is `connect()`'ing to you, to establish a connection between them. Then you can use `recv()` (and `send()`) on the new socket descriptor that `accept()` returns to you, eg:

```cpp
...
result = listen(fd, 1);
if (result < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed listen: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
}

// ADD THIS!!!
int clientfd = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
if (clientfd < 0) {
    ALOGI("Failed accept: %s, port:%d", strerror(errno), port);
}

// use client fd not listening fd!!!
char buffer[1024];
int bytes_received = recv(/*fd*/clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
...

// don't forget to close the client when finished...
close(clientfd);
...
```